# Red Tube API (Method getVideoEmbedCode)

Tags: json, video-encoding

As per the redtube API Documentation,

Method getVideoEmbedCode retrieves embed code (BASE64 encoded) for specific video by video_id parameter, which is useful to automatically embed videos.

for e.g sample method request
http://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.getVideoEmbedCode&video_id=38560&output=json

and the json response is as follows

```
{
"embed": {
    "code": "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"
  }
}
```

My question is... what do I do with this code or how do i use this in my html to embed the video?

Reference Source:
http://api.redtube.com/docs/#getVideoEmbedCode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the embed code for your porn site, you need to decode that base64 string:

```
var decoded = atob(response.embed.code)
```